# Getting the full source of an external javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to get the 'source' of a linked javascript file without using ajax ?
Basicly, I want to make a 'script viewer'.

So if my javascript would be linked like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="external_javascript.js"></script>
```

I would like to get the content/source of that javascript, without using ajax/XMLHttpRequest

Does anyone know if this is possible ?

Comment: Sure. You can write a server side script which accepts a URL as query string parameter. That would be the URL to the JS script and the server would have to retrieve the script. You can make a normal HTTP request to the server, it doesn't have to be an Ajax request.

Comment: I think that the point is to get the already loaded scripts without aditional requests to the server.

Comment: @Adam: If that's the case then the answer is: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd look to AJAX in the first place, and I'm not sure how you're approaching this issue or what server-side language you're programming in.

Having said that, if you're using PHP, I'd cURL the external JS after I processed the HTML of the page. This should get you the script back and you can display it as you wish.

You COULD use AJAX to call the PHP file that will process and display the JavaScript to make it all "async" like and stuff, but if you're attempting to write a script viewer, you won't need it.